# Create a time series with a known autocorrelation in R

Tags: r, simulation, autocorrelation, acf-pacf

I would like to create a time series in R that is going to have a known auto correlation. I tried creating two correlated variables and then parsing the time series (as shown below) but when i run `acf()` I am not getting the desired value.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(faux)

# create 2 vectors of random variables with 
# correlation of 10%
dat <- rnorm_multi(n = 1000, 
                   mu = c(0, 0),
                   sd = c(.02, .02),
                   r = c(0.1), 
                   varnames = c("A", "B"),
                   empirical = TRUE)
                   
# parse the data so that the next variable in 
# the series has a 10% correlation with the 
# previous variable
s = seq(1, (nrow(dat)*2-1), 2)
so = seq(2, (nrow(dat)*2), 2)
df = data.frame(value = rnorm(1000))

df[s, ] = dat$A
df[so, ] = dat$B
acf(df$value)
```

The value I am getting from lag 1 of the ACF is .05.

Comment: There is a huge number of ways to do this, depending on what *kind* of time series you want.  Should the underlying process be stationary? Autoregressive? Gaussian? *Etc.*, *etc.*

Comment: What you have there is the interweaved sequence $X_1^A, X_1^B, X_2^A, X_2^B...$. The issue with that is that the correlation between $X_t^B$ and $X_{t+1}^A$ is zero, so half the time you don't actually have the autocorrelation you asked for. Like @whuber is asking, if what you're looking for is literally the above (a normal AR(p)) then the easiest way is probably to derive the AR coefficients and simulate from the transition distribution one step at a time.

Comment: Thank you for the responses. My goal is to simulate a time series to figure out if my model is able to pick up on known trends. The distro can be Gaussian with 0 mean but to see how you would implement code to change drift,skew and kurtosis inputs would be very useful as well.